# Apache rewrite rule for all pages after domain name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I asked this question on stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466321/apache-rewrite-rule-for-all-pages-after-domain-name

Sorry for redirecting, but I wasn't aware of webmasters.stackoverflow and wasn't sure if I should repost it here or just link to it to prevent duplication.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
RewriteRule /(.*) http://archived.example.com/$1
```

This is redirecting *everything*, including example.com alone. I only want the redirect to happen if there is *something* (anything) after the ".com" (i.e. "/whatever"). I have a static HTML page that is now at example.com, but I want my old DB-backed site to go to archived.example.com.

Anymore ideas?

Comment: Don't duplicate questions. Ask that they be migrated. Requesting closure of the original over on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ^/(.+)
RewriteRule /(.*) http://archived.example.com/$1
```